# Elastic field mapping with tokenizer for numeric values, and have to execute via Java api

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I am trying to create a mapping for the field which containing alphanumeric values along with special characters like below

AB-7000-6000-Wk-21

am trying to create a pattern for this, please find my below pattern which I created.

```
  "tokenizer" : {
            "code" : {
               "pattern" : "[^\\p{L}\\d]+",
               "type" : "pattern"
            }
         },
```

This pattern is working fine with alphabets and its not working for alphanumeric and special characters.

so if I try to search

```
  get items/_search
{
   "query" : {
      "match" : {
         "code" : "7000-6000-"
      }
   }
}
```

I am expecting `AB-7000-6000-Wk-21` this result

Comment: I tried the same configuration. I am able to fetch the results. Aren't you getting `AB-7000-6000-Wk-21` in search results?

Comment: Nope am not getting., can you share your configuration?

Comment: The index I created looks like `PUT my_index
{"settings":{"analysis":{"analyzer":{"my_analyzer":{"tokenizer":"my_tokenizer"}},"tokenizer":{"my_tokenizer":{"type":"pattern","pattern":"[^\\p{L}\\d]+"}}}}}`. Then I posted a document using `POST my_index/test/1
{"code":"AB-7000-6000-Wk-21"}` . And then I ran this query `GET my_index/_search
{"query":{"match":{"code":"7000-6000-"}}}`. I am able to fetch the results.

Comment: Thankyou., let me try the same..

Comment: @Richa i also tested the same, its not working as per expected (query). if you insert some more documents in the same index then you try to query., its bringing all the documents

Comment: The reason for this is : The tokenizer you have defined tokenizes the code in the following way. Try running this : `GET my_index/_analyze
{"analyzer":"my_analyzer","text":["AB-7000-6000-Wk-21"]}` . It will show you the way tokens are getting generated. I have one question. Why have you used the above mentioned tokenizer.

Comment: Do you want query to return the documents that contains `7000-6000-`  but not `7000-1000-`

Comment: Yes. and am new to elasticsearch., but i have a requirement to search this pattern.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172994/discussion-between-richa-and-karthikeyan).